# how justify content works?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs containing image and  text. Outer container for background and inner container for width.  Div class name flex is display flex and set justify content space between which is not working? Why it is not working.

```css
.outer-main-container {
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
}

.inner-short-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-main-container">
  <div class="inner-short-container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="left-img">
        <img src="#" />
      </div>
      <div class="right-text">
        <h2> Header text will go here</h2>
        <p> You will find delightful art pieces. Photographs, Graphics, Craft, FoodBlogs, Foundation paper piecing and more </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's your goal or desired result?

Comment: Image on left side, text on right but there should be some space in between two which is not happening. Justify-conent : space between is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a flex amount to your flex children. `flex: 1`, this sets how a flex item will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container. `flex` is short for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and/or `flex-basis`.

The image I used in the example is ***980px X 815px*** and it is set to **100% width** in your CSS. It only fills up the available space alloted in your flex parent -> `flex:1` where the text is taking up `flex:2`, 2 times the parent elements space as the image.

```css
.outer-main-container {
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
}

.inner-short-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

 /* added this class from your html */
.left-img {
  flex: 1; 
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

 /* added this class from your html */
.right-text {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-main-container">
  <div class="inner-short-container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="left-img flow">
        <img src="https://www.rcsdk8.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/story/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="right-text flow">
        <h2> Header text will go here</h2>
        <p> You will find delightful art pieces. Photographs, Graphics, Craft, FoodBlogs, Foundation paper piecing and more </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is set to `100%` width forcing your text below it. Not sure what you want the dimensions on your image to be but change it from `100%` if you want them side by side.

You should also set a width on your text element if you don't want it to span 100% of the available space by default.

```css
.outer-main-container {
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
}

.inner-short-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 5rem; /* change this from 100% */
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #222;
}

.right-text {
  width: 20rem; /* give width to text */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-main-container">
  <div class="inner-short-container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="left-img">
        <img src="#" />
      </div>
      <div class="right-text">
        <h2> Header text will go here</h2>
        <p> You will find delightful art pieces. Photographs, Graphics, Craft, FoodBlogs, Foundation paper piecing and more </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They aligning side by side. Issue is no padding or space between them. ( justify content is set to space between so that image and text will not stick to each other but there is no space between them.) I gave image width 100% so that it will be responsive. Do I need to give image width : 100%  only for small screen size ?

Comment: @dbash you can set image width to any percent for it to be 'responsive'. `img { width: 60% }` will still scale the image width with the width of the browser. With your current HTML structure if you give the image and text container values that add up to = less than 100% you will have whatever's left over as space between them. Similar to my answer above. ( notice the space between image and text container )

Answer (score 0):

What you should note is that a block element will always take the entire space available to it. That is why the two section (ie. the image and the right text) are giving you that result.

Basically the `justify-content` property is working but the `image` is taking up 100% of space available to it and the other div, since it has only block elements, it takes 100% of space. One easy way would be to just add margin between the boxes; however, I have some other alternatives.

What you could do is try to give your image a width -- within the tag itself rather than setting it to 100%, because this way it will always fill the left div and get closer to the right div. You could also use `flex: 1` on the two `div` to ensure they share space correctly.

CSS:

```
.outer-main-container {
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
}

.inner-short-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-img, .right-text{
  flex: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-main-container">
<div class="inner-short-container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="left-img">
            <img width="200px" src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/newscms/2019_41/3044956/191009-cooking-vegetables-al-1422-3044956.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="right-text">
            <h2> Header text will go here</h2>
            <p> You will find delightful art pieces. Photographs, Graphics, Craft, FoodBlogs, Foundation paper piecing  and more </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other way around is to use `display: grid` this way and use a `grid-gap` between the elements:

CSS:

```
.outer-main-container {
  padding: 3em 0em;
  background-color: #f7f0e8;
}

.inner-short-container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
 }

.left-img, .right-text{
  flex: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-main-container">
<div class="inner-short-container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="left-img">
            <img width="200px" src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/newscms/2019_41/3044956/191009-cooking-vegetables-al-1422-3044956.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="right-text">
            <h2> Header text will go here</h2>
            <p> You will find delightful art pieces. Photographs, Graphics, Craft, FoodBlogs, Foundation paper piecing  and more </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```